# cannot convert void to an object in asp.netcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have written an api end point in asp.net core and getting error cannot convert void to an object
I am getting error in line.What I understand is SendEmailReminder method returns void but how do I handle that in the controller. If I remove await the error goes but then I get the warning that the method would be executed synchronously. Could somebody help

```
return Ok(await _counterpartyProposalService.SendEmailReminder());
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("sendEmailReminder")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmailReminders()
 {
    return Ok(await _counterpartyProposalService.SendEmailReminder());
 }



  public async Task SendEmailReminder()
  {
     var stepCode = StepCodes.BasicInformation;
     var command = _commandResolver(stepCode, null);
     await command.ExecuteEmailReminder();
  }
```

Comment: `await _counterpartyProposalService.SendEmailReminder(); return Ok()`? why overcomplicate things?

Comment: Your `SendEmailReminder` function returns an untyped Task.  Once you `await` it, there is no return type.  `Task` is conceptually equivalent to `Task<void>`.  When you call `Ok`, it is expecting there to be a parameter - any parameter.  You don't have one.  I believe you can get away with `await`ing the call to `SendEmailReminder`, and, once that's finished just calling `Ok()`

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code in the following manner, assuming that your HTTP call is not returning any content. By doing this, you will return HTTP 204.

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("sendEmailReminder")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmailReminders()
 {
    await _counterpartyProposalService.SendEmailReminder();
    NoContent();
 }

  public async Task SendEmailReminder()
  {
     var stepCode = StepCodes.BasicInformation;
     var command = _commandResolver(stepCode, null);
     await command.ExecuteEmailReminder();
  }
```

This is the signature of `Ok` method:

`public virtual OkObjectResult Ok([ActionResultObjectValue] object value)`

The reason you do not get the error, when you remove the `await` keyword is because `Ok` is taking the `Task` object as input.